# Visual Studio: What is the difference between excluded and ignored files?

Tags: version, controls

In the project I am working on, there are some files that are excluded (dimmed out) and some files that are ignored (file name has a red minus sign to the left). What is the difference between exclude and ignore? Can someone please give a concrete example to illustrate the use case of each of these terms?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using IDEs like `visual studio`, `phpstorm` and etc. You should know that they index your files and codes to help you with methods, properties and etc suggestions and autocompleting to simplify you coding.

As you know there are some files in every project that are not useful codes and they do not need to get indexed for autocompleting and etc, (files like `logs`, `caches`, and things like that).

In this situation you put these files and directories as excluded in your IDE to prevent indexing them. This will make your IDE super faster because their garbage collector knows whats going on now. And this will also use less ram and `cache` for its process.

But about ignoring files in `version control systems` such as `git`.

As you probably know, `vcs` systems like `git` keep track of every part and version of your source code with your commits.

So whenever you put a file or directory in you `vcs` ignore file, you tell the system not to keep the track of that files changes, and don't let anyone to commit it because usually its a system file and there is no need for it to be in the source code.